# Playframework, custom body parsers in java --> FormUrlEncoded

Tags: java, json, forms, playframework-2.5

I am trying to find an example to write a custom body parser like [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaBodyParsers#Composing-an-existing-body-parser)

but for [BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/mvc/BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.html), this is a JSON example:

```
'{"name":"nameValue",
  "emails":[{"email":"email1@domain"}, {"email":"email2@domain"}]}'
```